# Если способы перевода информации из инфоблока битрикс в более упощенную форму для печати?

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Проблема такая: есть много элементы инфоблока (заказы). В каждом храниться информация об этом заказе.[image: заказы]

Как передать вот эти поля в более упрощенную форму для печати (например в таблицу html или в документ хотя бы). Подскажите способ.

Comment: В чем сложность, в получении полей?

Comment: @DaVASrK, сложность в том, что поля берутся рандомного  заказа через api, а не этого конкретного например